# custom label for text_field rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
f.text_field(:user_id, value: 'user id')
```

is generating `label tag`

```
<label  class="control-label">User</label>
```

How can I generate

```
<label  class="control-label">User Id</label>
```

from `text_field` helper

Comment: `text_field` wont generate a label. You should use `f.label`

Comment: are you using `bootstrap-4/ bootstrap_form_for`, then you can hide label and add your own, `hide_label: true`

Comment: Something like this ?
 `<div>
  <%= f.label :user_id, "User Id" %>
</div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
= f.text_field(:user_id, label: 'User Id')
```

Answer (score 1):

This also should work

```
<%= f.label :user_id do %>
  User Id: <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
<%= f.label :user_id, 'User Id' %>
<%= f.text_field :user_id %>
```